# The python code doesn't print anything

Tags: python, regex

I have written the following codes to crawl some data, like the following lines:

```
import urllib.request, re

def get_content(page):
    url = 'https://www.liepin.com/zhaopin/?sfrom=click-pc_homepage-centre_searchbox-search_new&key=python&curPage=1'.format(page)
    a = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    html = a.read()
    html = html.decode('utf-8')
    #print (html)
    return html

def get(html):
    reg = re.compile(r'class="job-info" >[^.]+<span class="job-name" title="(.*?)" >.*?',re.S)
    items = re.findall(reg, html)
    return items

for j in range(1,10):
    html = get_content(j)

    for i in get(html):
        print (i)
        with open("liepin.txt",'a')as f:
            f.write(i)`
```

However, it doesn't print anything. Then I doubt that may be caused by the re, so i check the regex, but the -Regex Pal tell me that my re is right, it can match the html.

So can someone tell me what the problem is and how to solve it?

Comment: Does `get_content` work as it should? Have you tested the regular expression to make sure it works (https://regex101.com/ is a great place to do that)? Have you checked what `get` returns?

Comment: It prints stuff for me. A bunch of lines with Chinese symbols wrapping "Python" e.g. `招聘Python开发工程师`

Comment: try some print statements in your get function before and after the regex, printing html and printing items, that way you can see if your regex is somehow removing everything despite what regex pal says

Comment: Also why are you opening and closing the file in each iteration of the for loop? Switch the nesting order of the `with` and `for` blocks

Comment: It does print as Tagc mentioned. Probably, you have sent too many requests and they have blocked your IP.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic since we can't reproduce the issue, so it's not a problem with the code itself.

Comment: thanks, i have tried  run it yesterday, and it returned me something i want. so it's a problem with the net, instead of the code itself.

Comment: perhaps the net only allows people to request data once in 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Use this parser for this problems https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/